# Unknown undeleteable, unformattable partition

Tags: partitioning, filesystems, rootkit

I had two partitions on my hard drive labeled as unknown in gParted that showed up out of nowhere. I use 3 OS's on my computer, Windows which I just recently deleted, Backtrack5, and Ubuntu 12.04 which I am running gParted on. I tried to delete both of the suspicious partitions assuming it was a rootkit or something similar I got from Windows but was only able to format one; the other refused both deletion and formatting. Can someone help me remove these partitions? Look at the partitions labeled "Unallocated" and "/dev/sda6". [image]

Comment: Have you tried booting off a Live CD and trying to delete it from gparted there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- "unallocated" is not a partition, it is free space between partitions, hence you cannot delete it, only fill it with partitions :)
- As for /dev/sda6, I would go with Randolph West's suggestion to try to delete it using a live CD, either using gparted, or using `fdisk /dev/sda` if that fails.